# Html "Select" tag should not open its "OPTIONS" on "Enter" button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

*I have a Select element, So usually when the control "focus" in in Select element and then we hit Enter Button so the OPTION is shown. So my issue is that I dont want to open it on Enter Press , I only want to open Select element throught Mouse click.*

Comment: So what do you want to achieve?

Comment: select elememnt options only open on click, on control focus it is not opened.

Comment: @vishnu, do you want to stop the user to access the select tag using the keyboard or specifically "enter"? because using arrow keys will also open up the options

Comment: I want it to open only with mouse click but not with keyboard enter hit.

Comment: Maybe there is some valid use case for this, but generally keyboard navigation is a must-have to all applications. A best practice is to always consider accessibility (e.g. ADA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Event.preventDefault()` to prevent default action taken by browser, this should prevent the `select` element open when **space** or **enter** pressed.

**vanilla js**

```
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**jQuery**

```
$('select').keypress(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that keyboard accessibility is one of the core tenants of accessibility on the web. By disabling the ability for users to open selects you are rendering your UI unusable by people with disabilities who may not be able to use a regular mouse/trackpad.

Browsers do the right thing by default, please don't work against them!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question what you think..., this may be the answer:

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title>Single Listbox Select Element</title>
</head>
<body>
<select size="2" style="height:1.5em;width:3em">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
   <option>6</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) event and [prevent the default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) action if the enter key is pressed. You can check if it's the enter key by checking the `key`, `keyCode` or `which` based on browser compatibility.

e.g.

```js
document
  .getElementById("select")
  .addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter" || (e.keyCode || e.which) === 13)
      e.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
<select id="select">
    <option>aaa</option>
    <option>bbb</option>
    <option>ccc</option>
</select>
```